# uwp beforetextchanged cursor moving in front of text

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox

I've got a text box in UWP.  I'm trying to enforce only numbers in it.  Doing this inside the beforetextchanged event works ...

```
args.Cancel = args.NewText.Any(c => !char.IsDigit(c));
```

But, the issue I'm having is that if you enter a non digit when the text box is empty and then enter let's say "1" then "2" then "3", the text box shows "231".  The cursor gets in front of the first digit entered.  How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `TextChanged` event handler, like this:

```cs
private void TestBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (TestBox.Text.Length == 1)
    {
        TestBox.SelectionStart = TestBox.Text.Length;
        TestBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, that did it.